# Objective-C how to check if a string is null

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, null

SO
I wish to check to see if the item in my array `[clientDataArray objectForKey:@"ClientCompany"]` is `nil`.

```
    temp = [clientDataArray objectForKey:@"ClientCompany"];
    if (temp != [NSNull null]) infofieldCompany.text = temp;
```

So far I have been able to achieve this through the above code, but it does give me the warnings

- warning: `NSArray` may not respond to `-objectForKey:`
- warning: comparison of distinct
  Objective-C types `struct NSNull *`
  and `struct NSString *` lacks a cast

My main interest is the second warning, but the first warning also interest me. 
How should I adapt my above code?

Comment: The clientDataArray was actually an NSDictionary, but was declared as array, thus the warning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your first warning looks like you're trying to call `objectForKey` on an `NSArray`. Which isn't going to work, as `NSArray` doesn't have an `objectForKey` method.

As for the second warning you can just compare directly with nil, ie:

```
if (temp != nil)
```

or since nil is equivalent to 0, you can also just do:

```
if (temp)
```

Comment: yeah, I should have done that. Nice and simple too.
The first line i posted does indeed work fine, but I will have a rethink of it.

Comment: Please notice that this won't if temp is an NSString. Use Robinsons' answer

Answer (score 17):

After trying all the options, i think this is the best option to comapre NSString null

```
if ( temp != ( NSString *) [ NSNull null ] )
{
  // do some thing
}
```

Comment: What advantages does this have over `temp != nil`?

Answer (score 14):

Both of the answers previously given missed a fundamental point: you can't put `nil` into an array, so you'll never get `nil` out of an array. **Using `NSNull` as a placeholder in an array is the correct thing to do,** however your variable `temp` then cannot be declared as an `NSString *`, as it might not be one. Use either `NSObject *` or `id` as the type of the variable to suppress the comparison warning.

Comment: or do [string isEqual:[NSNull null]]

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to test NULL or Empty values:

```
if (yourObj.yourString == (NSString*) [NSNull null] || yourObj.yourString.length == 0 )
{
   yourObj.yourString = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quiet simple

```
if (myString == nil){
     NSLog(@"myString is null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is (I mean the second warning) is that you're comparing NSString object, which could be set to null to an NSNull object.

Have you tried the usual C way of checking for null?

```
if(temp) {
// It's not null, do something.
}
```

I'm not 100% sure about this one, but you could try it. If you did, sorry that couldn't provide more useful information.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The `NSNull` singleton can be used to build "interleaved" arrays like obj0, obj1, obj2, NSNull, obj3, NSNull, ..., nil.

> warning: 'NSArray' may not respond
>   to'-objectForKey:'

NSArray does not implement `objectForKey`.
Your code will crash at runtime (if `clientDataArray` has been allocated and initialized)
You can access array elements by index ([objectAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDJBFC)).
If you need to associate objects with keys, take a look at [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

> if (temp != nil)
>
> or since nil is equivalent to 0, you can also just do:
>
> if (temp)

I am not by any stretch of the imagination a Obj-C or Cocoa expert, in C/C++ you can use something like:

if(somePtr != NULL)

And, unless you explicitly, set it to NULL or changed what it was pointing to,
you can be certain, that it is, in fact, Not Null or Null (what-ever you were looking for...)

But I have noticed (my personal experience anyway) that in Obj-C,

If you do something like:
if(someObj != nil) or the converse,

There's no Guarantee, it will tell you it's REAL status...

So (after dealing with a bunch of crashes) when I deal with Obj-C (BS), to be safe, I always have a BOOL or flag set up to track it's status, so you don't end up Free-ing, excuse me... "Release-ing" something that has already be deallocated...

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is old, I hope My Answer will help some one else.

You can try this

```
temp = [clientDataArray objectForKey:@"ClientCompany"];
if (![temp isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) infofieldCompany.text = temp;
```