# Is this string null or not

Tags: iphone, nsstring

This is the output of my string in console.

```
device type-------------(
mobile,
"<null>",
tablet
```

How to deal with the 2nd value. I tried the following way, but doesn't work app gets kill here on these lines.

```
if([dType isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
if([dType isEqualToString:@""])
if([dType isEqualToString:@"null"])
```

None of the above work. Please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this if[dType length]== 0;

Comment: On my first google hit I found:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482276/how-can-i-test-an-nsstring-for-being-nil And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401234/objective-c-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (dType == (NSString *)[NSNull null])
    {
       // your logic here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the string. It's always advisable you check the length of string. Like :

```
[yourString length] == 0
```

And, check the condition. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899209/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-empty-in-objective-c). Hope this help.

Comment: it is giving error this way.  -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e6678.

Comment: @iPhone : [NSNull length]: this is wrong. You have to send your string here. For eg [yourStrin length] == 0 if it equals to 0, that means it's a null,nil or "" string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if **[string length] == 0.** This will check if it's a valid but empty **string (@"")** as well as if its nil, since calling length on nil will also return 0.

Alternatively, you can try with `[string isEqual:[NSNull null]];` also

Answer (score 0):

I use two macros for this its in my Defines.h file

```
#define NULLVALUE(m)                    (m == nil ? @"" : m)
#define NULLVALUE1(m)                    (m == nil ? @" " : m)
```

It changes null value to ""  or space " " easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

you can check that like this

```
if ([YOUR_STRING isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || YOUR_STRING == nil ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *) removeNull:(NSString *) string {

    if ([string isEqual:[NSNull null]] ) {
        return @"";
    }

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"<null>"]) {
        return @"";
    }
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
        return @"";
    }
    @try {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"null"];
        ////////NSLog(@"in removeNull : %d  >>>> %@",range.length, string);
        if (range.length > 0 || string == nil) {
            string = @"";
        }
        range = [string rangeOfString:@"<null>"];
        ////////NSLog(@"in removeNull : %d  >>>> %@",range.length, string);
        if (range.length > 0 || string == nil) {
            string = @"";
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return @"";
    }
    @finally {

    }


    string = [self trimString:string];
    return string;
}
```

------------------------------ call like this
    NSString *strFb = [classname removeNull:YourString];